# How to find out all installed software in our RedHat Enterprise 5 server?

Tags: linux, redhat, installation

We're moving servers and I need to make a list of all software installed in our server so we could install it too in the new one we'll get.

Current server details:

- Redhat Enterprise Linux 5
- Using Virtualmin / Webmin to do occasional config changes
- I know basic SSH commands, enough to move files around, restart services, install & uninstall, etc.

Is there a command I could use to make a list of all installed software in our server? And also possibly find out what version we're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of all installed rpms, you can do `rpm -qa`. To find out which config files have changed, you can again use rpm: `rpm -qa | xargs sudo rpm -q --verify --nosize`

Anything that was installed without using rpms is a wild guess, but you should get a good idea from looking at `/opt`, `/usr/local` and `/home`

Comment: Just want to add another way to make a list of installed software: yum list installed

Answer (score 1):

If you install all rpm packages then you can type `rpm -qa` to give you a list.
There are other ways to install software (like tarballs) and those aren't tracked ( by the rpm database or any other method that I'm aware of.).